# How to import my wallet?

Tags: client, wallet-import

I used to run bitcoin on Ubuntu and I have a wallet with 1 coin in it.

I took a backup of my `~/.bitcoin` directory which includes a `wallet.dat` file.

Now I'm running on a mac, using the bitcoint-qt client.

How do I get back the money from that wallet?

Can I just copy it over the existing wallet that the mac client generated?

Is there a way to run a command line client and point to my wallet then transfer coins from it to the new wallet?

Comment: I'm wondering why you can't just send the coins from your original wallet to your new one?

Comment: @T9b yea that's a good point. I have no idea why I didn't do that back then! I can't remember if there was some specific reason or if I simply did not think of it

Answer (score 11):

I got it to work by simply copying the file over.

An important point to notice if you intend to follow this suggestion:

My mac wallet had 0 coins

If your mac wallet has coins, then don't follow this solution.

First I shut down the bitcoin-qt client. Not sure if this step is necessary but I think it's safer.

Then I copied the wallet.dat file over to

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat
```

Then start the bitcoint-qt client again. It might take a bit longer to startup than usual. Don't panic and let it take its time.

Then you will see your coins in the client!

Comment: That is correct.  You overwrite your wallet on the Mac, but like you mentioned, it had 0 coins.  Never hurts to make a backup copy first before overwriting if you've ever used the walet.

Comment: As far as shutting down the client before copying the wallet, that is correct.  You never want to copy data while an application that accesses it is open.

Comment: I'm on Linux, I exported the encrypted wallet.dat from Windows but I can't just overwrite it with the one Windows generated. it simply crashes with "Runaway exception, can't open wallet.dat, error 22"

Comment: so if anyone somehow got hold of my "wallet.dat", he/she can just copy the file over to his system and, now he/she has all my coins ?